# JavaScript - Get text in div by class

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get just the content/text of div by class name using javascript. The outcome isn't what i have expected. I did try to push it into array but it does not seems to be working. Please help!

What i have done so far :

JavaScript:

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByClassName("headline-bar");

window.onload = function() {

    var year= document.getElementById("year");
    for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
    {
        var Entry = document.createElement("option");
        Entry.text = elements[i];
        year.add(Entry ,null);
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<form>
<select id="year">
</select>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

 <div class="headline-bar">2015</div>  
 <div class="headline-bar">2014</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Desire outcome:

[image]

Comment: is  the code in the <head>? var elements will be undefined until loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), *The `Node.textContent` property represents the text content of a node and its descendants*

```js
var elements = document.body.getElementsByClassName("headline-bar");

window.onload = function() {
  var year = document.getElementById("year");
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var Entry = document.createElement("option");
    Entry.text = elements[i].textContent;
    year.add(Entry, null);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="year">
  </select>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<div class="headline-bar">2015</div>
<div class="headline-bar">2014</div>
```